# CSS "overflow" culls "background-color"

Tags: html, css, background, overflow

I'm trying to style blocks of code for a website. The container div is set to overflow both vertically and horizontally. The problem is when it overflows horizontally, the zebra-striped background-color is culled. I tried it with a background image as well but it culls that too. Why is it doing that and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Image: http://zero.robotrenegade.com/q3w/background-overflow.png

Webpage (scale your browser width down to see the problem): http://zero.robotrenegade.com/q3w/code.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="created" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="all" title="Default styles" />
    <title></title>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("pre code").html(function(index, html) {
                    return html.replace(/^(.*)$/mg, "<span class=\"line\">$1</span>")
            });
        });
    </script>
<style>
.codeblock {
    max-height: 25em;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: normal;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.codeblock h1, .codeblock p {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0em 1em 0.5em 3.5em;
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.codeblock pre {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-face: 'lucida console',monaco,courier,'courier new',monospace;
}
.codeblock pre code {
    counter-reset: line-numbering;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.codeblock pre code .line::before {
    content: counter(line-numbering);
    counter-increment: line-numbering;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    width: 4.5em;
    text-align: right;
    color: #888;
    border-right: 1px dotted #888;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.codeblock pre code .line {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 -1.2em 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.codeblock pre code .line:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f2f5f9;
}
/*.codeblock pre code .line:hover {
    background: #4b95e5;
    color: #fff;
}*/
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="codeblock"><!--<h1>Hello, this is an optional header.</h1>-->
<pre><code>void idAF::Restore( idRestoreGame *savefile ) {
    savefile->ReadObject( reinterpret_cast<idClass *&>( self ) );
    savefile->ReadString( name );
    savefile->ReadBool( hasBindConstraints );
    savefile->ReadVec3( baseOrigin );
    savefile->ReadMat3( baseAxis );
    savefile->ReadInt( poseTime );
    savefile->ReadInt( restStartTime );
    savefile->ReadBool( isLoaded );
    savefile->ReadBool( isActive );

    animator = NULL;
    modifiedAnim = 0;

    if ( self ) {
        SetAnimator( self->GetAnimator() );
        Load( self, name );
        if ( hasBindConstraints ) {
            AddBindConstraints();
        }
    }

    savefile->ReadStaticObject( physicsObj );

    if ( self ) {
        if ( isActive ) {
            // clear all animations
            animator->ClearAllAnims( gameLocal.time, 0 );
            animator->ClearAllJoints();

            // switch to articulated figure physics
            self->RestorePhysics( &physicsObj );
            physicsObj.EnableClip();
        }
        UpdateAnimation();
    }
}</code></pre>
<!-- <p>This is an optional footer, goodbye!</p> -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for interesting question, pretty curious for the answer..

Comment: if all else fails, you could of course always put a repeated background image (white/grey) on the .codeblock - that should be a pretty solid (though not very sexy) workaround.

Comment: @ptriek background image on '.codeblock' won't work since it won't scroll with the text, which defeats the point of zebra stripping. If anything, background image would be applied to either 'pre' or 'code', but then you end up with the same background culling issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `float:left` on the `.codeblock pre`. Works in Firefox.

`<pre>` fits itself inside the `.codeblock` container like there was no more room. `float` makes your `<pre>` element wide just enough to fit its content.

UPDATE

```
.codeblock pre {
    float: left;
    min-width: 100%;}
```

Works in Firefox, Opera, IE9 and WebKit

As far as I understand, it elements inside a container with `overflow:auto` fit themselves inside the area that's visible by default. Those elements' `width:100%` is only as wide as the outer container. In this example inside of the inner container you have a `code` tag that doesn't break lines so the text goes outside the inner container and makes the outer container show scrolls. To avoid that, you need the inner container to fit its content hence `float:left`.

But, as you cleverly noticed (and I didn't), this way it won't expand if the outer container is wider than the code so to avoid that you need to put `min-width:100%` to make the inner container use at least all the visible space inside the outer container.

Comment: ok, solves the problem - but creates a new one: width of the rows will not expand to 100% on a broader screen

Comment: Updated. But to get complete understanding you should look at the w3 specification.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! Works perfectly. I've been staring at this problem for 2 days.

Comment: Why `float`? That's a weird hack. Just use `display: inline-block` instead. That does the same thing without floating the element.

Answer (score 2):

Lines are expanding like every block element to the maximum width - and that is without overflow. And they are not connected - if one is bigger, it does not affect others.

Try changing them to something else than block element, like that:

```
.codeblock pre code .line {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Table-related types change width or height (cells) together

http://jsfiddle.net/D7rND/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.codeblock pre, .codeblock pre code {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This worked for me in Safari.

Comment: same problem as @szym answer, background won't expand in broader browser

Comment: Yes, I forgot to go back and expand the browser.  Sorry.

Comment: Just add `min-width: 100%` and it'll work the way the OP expects for short lines.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `{float:left}` to the div's whose backgrounds were being "culled" in my situation.

With this change the backgrounds and borders would extend with the overflowed text. 
So as I scroll horizontally the text is displayed uniformly with the same background and borders.

Before adding this piece of css, the background/border would not overflow beyond div, although the text would.

Answer (score -1):

Use a proper DTD format.it's good on firefox though...

Comment: What? `<!doctype html>` triggers standards mode, this is the best you can do.